# Different asp.net core logic on localhost and in Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.1

My `Asp.Net Core 2.1 Razor` pages web app uses `Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` which contains the tag `<partial name="_LoginPartial" />`. If it is running at `localhost`, while published in `Azure`, `Pages/_LoginPartial.cshtml` is used instead of `Pages/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml`. Additionally, if I delete `Pages/_LoginPartial.cshtml` and deploy the app, the Azure server shows an older non-existent version of `Pages/_LoginPartial.cshtml`. It looks like some sort of caching is happening. My questions are:

1. Why is the `Azure` server not using `Pages/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml` rather than the "non-existent" page?
2. From where is the server getting `Pages/_LoginPartial.cshtml` when it is deleted instead of existent `Pages/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml`?

Comment: Make sure your deployment has "remove additional files at destination" enabled. The old file might still actually be out there. You can verify using the kudu tools or Cloud Explorer in Visual Studio to view the files on the server.

Comment: Great and useful comment! There was outdated `project_name.PrecompiledViews.dll` which should be deleted! It seems, that PrecompiledViews.dll is not produced anymore but may be used if present

Comment: your code was supposed to recompile the dll and update it. if you had to use the remove files option, you can try recreating your publish profile.